# How to push work to my own private repo while still pulling updates from Github?

Tags: git

I'm starting by telling you I'm confused.  I know what I *think* I want to do but I'm not even sure how to go about doing it.

What I *think* I want to accomplish is to clone a public repo from Github but have that repo be stored on a different machine than the one I'm sitting at.

Or maybe you tell me - ...

There is a public Github repo - a template for a web app (https://github.com/WHMCS/templates-six)

- I need to clone this repo (and also be able to keep pulling future changes and updates to it)
- I need to be able to modify this repo on my (Windows) workstation at home
- I need to be able to keep my modified repo on my [shared hosting] web server. (access by ftp or ssh over Internet only)
- I don't want to have to login to the web server separately to push/pull/sync changes; this should be in sync automatically.  Since I don't actually need the changes locally (I can't run the app locally, only on the Webserver) I think my 'local' repo should just live on that filesystem but maybe this assumption is wrong.
- If there are ever any conflicts, I need to be able to resolve them without clobbering my local files and possibly without ever accepting changes from the upstream.

I've tried searching (here, google, github help docs, others) but I think maybe the terminology keeps messing me up and I'm not finding my scenario.  Between locals and remotes and clients and repos and forks I've lost my way.  Or maybe it's impossible?  idk.

I'd appreciate someone explaining how to do this if it can be or, if it's really just simple/basic stuff, then just point out please the right terminology at each end and I'll go back to searching it out.

Or maybe I've really scrambled it all in which case suggest a way to approximate the end result.

Thanks

Comment: Git's default behavior already seems to cover most of your requirements.  Git is a decentralized version control system, meaning that you can work and version things locally, completely detached from the remote, as you need.  Then, you'd only need to periodically sync up, to keep things current.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Perhaps what you say is true, however getting from A to B does not seem so straightforward.  I asked some specific questions.  Perhaps you can provide some specific answers or at least pointers in the right direction?  If I need to expand detail in the question, please point out what.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually pretty straightforward with Git. There are many ways to do it; here is what I would do:

1. Clone the repo onto your workstation, wherever you want the project to live. `git clone git@github.com:WHMCS/templates-six.git`
2. Now, `cd templates-six`. From here on out, we'll be running our git commands inside this repository folder.
3. By default, git created a [remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) named `origin`. For clarity, we're going to rename it. Run `git remote rename origin github`
4. Create a bare repository on your shared hosting webserver. Call it whatever you want. There may be a way to do this in the UI, or you can do it in the terminal with something similar to `git init --bare foobar.git`.
5. Back on your own workstation, add the shared webserver as a remote. You'll need to figure out the appropriate address to use here, but it should be similar to this, which uses SSH (same as you'd use to log in). `git remote add webserver ssh://joelaz@sharedhost.com:/home/joelaz/foobar.git`
6. Push `master` branch up to the webserver. `git push webserver master:master`. If that doesn't work for some reason, it should be safe to try `-f`, since there's no history you care about on the remote server.
7. I'd set the upstream branch to your own webserver. `git branch -u webserver/master`. Now, by default, `git push` will push to your webserver.

With this setup, whenever you want to get updates from Github, you can `git fetch github` and then `git merge github/master`, which merges `github`'s master branch into your own local master branch. Finally, as before, `git push` sends it to your webserver. You'll have to maintain the code on your workstation (which is probably a good idea anyway), and you'll make changes and fix merge conflicts there before pushing the code to `webserver` with `git push`.

To help you understand what's happening, keep in mind that each of the 3 repositories (Github, workstation, server) maintains its own copy of the code, and it's own copy of any branches. You move code between the repositories by pulling and pushing from the repository on your workstation.

Comment: Thank you so much @mkasberg.  I'll come back and accept once I try but reading it like this makes good sense now.  The one thing I'm still not sure of/clear on - the origin (github) is read only.  The clone on my workstation is for making modifications.  Therefore later when I pull changes from origin, I may (probably) never resolve all the conflicts.  These are my intended changes after all. So will Git be ok with this and later let me pull again the Master branch even though I never resolve all conflicts?   Or do I keep my mods on a different branch and push THAT to my web server remote?

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting that the github repository would be read-only in your case. There isn't any need for you to push your modifications back to github. Don't think of the master branch in github and the master branch on your workstation as the same branch. They are different branches. The branch on your workstation is a branch that was created from the master branch on github, and you can continue to merge github's master branch into your workstation's master branch (i.e. pull) as often as you like, with no need to ever merge your branch into github's branch.

Comment: Also, be careful with the way you're using "resolve all the conflicts". I think what you mean is the code on your workstation and the code in github will permanently diverge (your changes will never be merged back to github). That's different than what it means to "resolve all conflicts". You _might_ have merge conflicts when you pull updates from github (e.g. when you both change the same line). You'll have to resolve these merge conflicts once, and then they _will_ be resolved and you won't have to deal with them again. In resolving the conflict, you can choose to keep your changes.

Comment: If you prefer to name the branch on your workstation something different and push THAT to your web server, you can do that. And you should, if it makes it easier to you to understand. Really, it's an identical solution because branch names in Git have no special meaning (other than convention) and "master" on you workstation need not have any relation to "master" on github.

Comment: Awesome @mkasberg.  Thank you so much for laying that all out.  It actually makes a lot of sense now.  And I like the idea of renaming branches (I would not have thought of that on my own at this stage) to clarify for myself the relationships.  Will probably make it easier/more sensible to follow and grok git cli commands.   Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read the first three chapters of [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). It is free online and covers the majority of commands you need to perform tasks like this. It isn't very long. Just read a little every day and before you know it, you'll be a Git master. Eventually, you will also need to read some in the later chapters about using git on the server.

Comment: Appreciate the sentiment though you word it as though I put no effort forth.  I actually have read most of that (first 2 chapters and parts of 3rd).  Clearly it didn't sink in or make sense as much as I'd wanted the first time through.  Hence formulating my question.  It's not as though I asked without trying to figure it out.  The terminology around Git isn't the most straightforward; agree?  I didn't realize that one could push to the web server and still maintain the relationship to the original origin like that.  It just wasn't clear so before I bork my website I sought clarification.